# Какому из классов (таблиц) принадлежат временные параметры?

Tags: модель-данных

**1.    Описание:**

Приходят данные о погоде, пример:

*Прогноз погоды на станции Мурманск на период с 10.08.2018 6:00 по 10.08.2018 21:00.

- C 6:00 до 15:00 Дождь
- С 15:00 до 18:00 Гроза с дождем*

В итоге, есть период прогноза, а есть периоды (в рамках периода прогноза) на котором прогнозируется какое-то явление.

**2.   Вопрос:**

Данные о временном периоде (пример: с 6:00 до 15:00) в течении которого наблюдается какое-то явление, порекомендуйте пожалуйста, в какой из классов (таблиц) он по вашему мнению принадлежит? И почему?

[image: Общая диаграмма]

[image: детальная откорректированная]

Comment: *есть период прогноза, а есть периоды (в рамках периода прогноза) на котором прогнозируется какое-то явление* Вас гнусно наобманули.  Есть период. В нём - или суммарный прогноз, или частный. Соответственно частные прогнозы просто ссылаются на суммарный. А сущность это одна и та же.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за внимание к вопросу. Частные прогнозы ссылаются на суммарный. А сущность одна и та же. А как на диаграмме это отображается? Или можете привести пример? Не совсем понял как это реализовать

Comment: Да я вообще не понимаю, зачем одиночные измеряемые атрибуты раскиданы по разным блокам (таблицам?)...

Comment: @Akina 1. Я не все измеряемые атрибуты отобразил на этой диаграмме, не стал отображать для исключения избыточности. Их много, Всего измеряемых атрибутов более 20. Вы рекомендует в одну таблицу "Метеоэлементы" их "сложить"?            2. По поводу Даты можете написать пояснение? Несовсем вас понял. "Частные прогнозы ссылаются на суммарный. А сущность одна и та же." А как на диаграмме это отображается? Или можете привести пример? Не совсем понял как это реализовать

Comment: *Всего измеряемых атрибутов более 20.* Это атрибуты. Не словарные, чисто значения, одно на экземпляр измерения. Что они делают НЕ в таблице сущности, атрибутами которой являются? *По поводу Даты можете написать пояснение?* Дата - тоже атрибут. Одиночный и не-словарный.

Comment: @Akina Приложил в теле вопроса новый рисунок. Посмотрите пожалуйста. Вот такое предполагается решение "..Частные прогнозы ссылаются на суммарный. А сущность одна и та же."?

Comment: Не-а. Почему два блока? Блок один - прогноз. Но у него есть атрибут "Родительский прогноз". И соответственно линк от атрибута "Идентификатор прогноза" к атрибуту "Родительский прогноз" того же блока. Эдаким полу-колечком... Ну или как в Аксессе - два блока-копии "Прогноз" и "Прогноз копия", и линк от одного к другому.

Comment: @Akina 1. Атрибуты "температура воздуха", "Явление погоды" являются Метеорологическими величинами и явлениями. Погода состоит из значений метеорологических величин и явлений. Соответственно метеорологические величины и явления в одной таблице, а погода другая таблица. Или вы имели ввиду, что все метеорологические величины и явления должны быть в одной таблице "Метеоэлементы"? А не ввиде отдельных таблиц на которую ссылается "Метеоэлемент"?    2. Вопрос по дате. Приложил новый рисунок. Такое решение вы имели ввиду? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Мы толчём воду в ступе. Проведите наконец нормальный анализ предметной области и выделите все сущности, атрибуты, связи и процессы. Только на основе результатов такого анализа можно построить правильную диаграмму. Неким мистическим вдохновением задачу не решить.

Comment: @Akina последний вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста. Приложил откорректированную диаграмму. Касательно Родительского прогноза. Вот так вы рекомендуете? А связь агрегация?

Comment: @Akina огромное спасибо! Напишите в виде отдельного ответа пжта, я отмечу как ответ.   (@Akina последний вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста. Приложил откорректированную диаграмму....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Метеорологические величины объединить в один класс
2. Явления вынести в отдельный класс, связь с классом погода.